# Stack Trace Logger

Tags: java, stack-trace

I need to write a parent Java class that classes using recursion can extend. The parent class will be be able to realize whenever the call stack changes ( you enter a method, temporarily leave it to go to another method call, or you are are finsihed with the method ) and then print it out. I want it to print on the console, but clear the console as well every time so it shows the stack horizantaly so you can see the height of each stack to see what popped off and what popped on... Also print out if a baseline was reached for recursive functions.

First. How can I using the StackTraceElements and Thread classes to detect automatically whenever the stack has popped or pushed an element on without calling it manually?

Second, how would I do the clearing thing?

For instance , if I had the code:

```
public class recursion(int i)
{ 
    private static void recursion(int i)
    {
        if(i < 10)
            System.out.println('A');
        else
        {
            recursion(i / 10 );
            System.out.println('B');
        }
    } 
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        recursion(102);
    }

}
```

It would need to print out the stack when entering main(), when entering recursion(102) from main(), when it enters recursion(102 / 10), which is recursion(10), from recursion(102), when it enters recursion(10 / 10), which is recursion(1) from recursion(10). Print out a message out when it reaches the baseline recursion(1).. then print out the stacks of reversed revisitation of function recursion(10), recursion(102) and main(). finally print out we are exiting main().

Comment: This would be better suited on SO. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE, it belongs on SO. If you question has you in front of a whiteboard, it belongs on Programmers. Please don't reask this question there as it can be migrated for you.

Comment: @Walter May you please move it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread` class allows managing OS threads, it does not have anything to do with the call-stack. `StackTraceElement` represents a stack-frame but you need a `StackTrace` to get to it.

You are looking for a notification for when the stack-trace changes, for example a frame is added (a method is entered) or removed (a method is exited).

By far the most appropriate tool for this task is [`AspectJ`](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/). It lets you define `advices` (a kind of method) that gets called (besides other cases) when other methods are entered or existed. These triggers that result in the advices getting called are called `pointcuts` -- they can be method entry, exit and the methods can be described using wildcards: the pointcut `MyClass.get*` applies to all get methods of MyClass.

Answer (score 0):

I started to write my own before seeing your answer. It is simplistic in form but the shell is:

package stackTraceLogger;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StackTraceLogger 
{

static final int MAX_ROW = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
static final int MAX_COLUMN = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

static public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> stringTrace;
//private ArrayList<ArrayList<StackTraceElement>> stack;


public StackTraceLogger()
{
     stringTrace = new ArrayList< ArrayList <String>>();
    //stack = new ArrayList<ArrayList<StackTraceElement>>();
}

static public void addStack(StackTraceElement[] inputTrace) 
{
        int size = inputTrace.length;
        // make an ArrayList with the strings of all the StrackTraceElements
        ArrayList<String> str = new  ArrayList<>(size);

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            str.add(i,inputTrace[i].getMethodName());
        }   

        // Add the ArrayList to the 2D ArrayList of the stacks

}
static public void printTrace()
{

/*  if(stringTrace.get(0).size() > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < stringTrace.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(stringTrace.get(i));
            for(int j = 0; j < stringTrace.get(j).size(); j++)
                System.out.println(stringTrace.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }*/
}

static private ArrayList<String> convertToArrayList(StackTraceElement[] inputTrace) 
{
    ArrayList<String> strTrace = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j = 0; j < inputTrace.length; j++ )
        strTrace.add(inputTrace[j].getMethodName());
    return strTrace;
}
}
```